# Calculate CPU usage of a pod in a namespace using Prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana

How to get the CPU usage of a pod in a namespace ? My initial dashboard on Grafana setup looks like this -
[image]

I'm trying to come up with a query, that gives me the CPU usage of a selected **pod** of selected **namespace** in selected **cluster**. Managed to come up with below one, but it returns "`No data`".

```
sum(node_namespace_pod_container:container_cpu_usage_seconds_total:sum_irate{pod="$pod", namespace="$namespace"})
```

Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: Check if the recording rule `node_namespace_pod_container:container_cpu_usage_seconds_total:sum_irate` exists in your prometheus UI's graph?

Comment: @YwH : I'm very new to Grafana and prometheus, could you please let me know, how can I verify that ?

Comment: @ChelMS, go to your prometheus `/rules` and look for recording rule with mentioned name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to calculate the workload CPU utilization per pod, in terms of usage seconds of CPU, you can use this `PromQL` query:

```
sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{namespace="$namespace",
  pod_name=~"$podName",container_name!=""}[1m])) by (pod_name)
```

where:

- `container_cpu_usage_seconds_total()` which gives you how long the CPU has been occupied
- `rate()` calculates the per-second average rate of increase of the time series in the range vector
- `[1m]` reads the values at the defined interval of 1 minute
- `sum() by (pod_name)` adds all values which contain the same pod names, necessary in case of multiple containers in the same pod
- `namespace="$namespace",pod_name=~"$podName",container_name!=""` applies the condition to get the pods to consider and filter the rest

If you want to calculate the workload memory utilization per pod, you can use this query:

```
sum(container_memory_working_set_bytes{namespace="$namespace",
  pod_name=~"$podName", container_name!=""}) by (pod_name)
```